# Select with multiple subselects on same table with parent-children like relations

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a table which contains data on machines. Among many other there are columns for the (unique) equipment number (EMEQP#), the financial cost (EMCOST), the current value (EMBOOK) and the equipment link (EMLEQP). Some machines are made up of several other machines, these are linked by putting the EMEQP# of the "parent" machine in the EMLEQP column. The EMLEQP of the parent is sometimes filled in (with its own EMEQP#) but can also be empty. Also not every parent has children, but even then the EMLEQP can be filled in or not.

Here's a simplified sample of the data:

```
EMEQP#    |  EMLEQP  |  EMCOST  |  EMBOOK  
ACMD001   |  ACMD001 |  10      |  12  
ACMD001A  |  ACMD001 |  8       |  1  
ACMD002   |  NULL    |  10      |  12  
SLE003    |  NULL    |  11      |  5
RUP5120   |  SLE003  |  12      |  7
```

So in this case ACMD001, ACMD002 and SLE003 are parent machines (because EMLEQP is empty or the same as EMEQP#. ACMD001A is a child of ACMD001 and RUP5120 a child of SLE003.

Result of the query should be:

```
EMEQP#   |  EMCOST  |  EMBOOK  
ACMD001  |  18      |  13  
ACMD002  |  10      |  12  
SLE003   |  23      |  12
```

I need to know the total EMCOST and EMBOOK of each machine, so the sum of the parent and any children. At first I tried using `group by` on EMLEQP, but this doesn't work as that can be empty on the parent.
Next I tried working with a subquery. The main query selects all the parents (`WHERE EMLEQP = EMEQP# OR EMLEQP = ''`) and the subselect calculates the sum of all machines where EMLEQP is the EMEQP# of the parent (or empty to include the parent as well). Here's what I have so far to calculate the EMCOST sum.

`SELECT EMEQP#, 
    (SELECT SUM(b.emcost)
    FROM uv_EQPMASFL AS b
    WHERE 
    (b.emleqp = a.emeqp#  AND b.emeqp# <> a.emeqp# OR b.emeqp# = a.emeqp#) 'EMCOST'
FROM uv_EQPMASFL a
WHERE
(EMLEQP = EMEQP# or EMLEQP = '')`

This query works, but is extremely slow. It takes over 15 minutes to run it and I haven't even added the second sum to it. Since I cannot use two columns in a subquery, I will need to add a second subquery to get the second sum. Finally I would also like it if I could get another column to indicate the number of machines which are part of the parent (parent included).

There must be a better, more efficient way to get this data, but I'm not seeing how.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After the suggestion from @XAMT, I took another approach and was able to fix this.
For anyone interested, I first `SELECT` the data where EMLEQP is not empty (so all children and parents with their own EMEQP# in EMLEQP and then `UNION` that with a `SELECT` of the data where EMLEQP is empty.
From that selection I take another `SELECT` which I `GROUP BY` EMEQP#

Comment: It's nice to solve it by yourself but I tested it with sample data and it is working well. so maybe you have a problem with real data or `Join condition` as I said before.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to write it with `CTE` instead of `nesting select` and I'm sure it will be executed in a second for about 10k data if you do not have an `INDEX` issue :

```
With CTE As (
    SELECT
        emleqp,
        emeqp#,
        SUM(emcost) as EMCOST
    FROM uv_EQPMASFL
    GROUP BY emleqp, emeqp#
)

SELECT
    EMEQP#, 
    b.EMCOST
FROM uv_EQPMASFL a
LEFT JOIN CTE AS b ON b.emleqp = a.emeqp#  AND b.emeqp# <> a.emeqp# OR b.emeqp# = a.emeqp#
Where a.EMLEQP = a.EMEQP# or a.EMLEQP = ''
```

Please recheck the `JOIN` condition because you need `parenthesis` for `AND` and `OR` combined.

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't really work. I got a lot of duplicate values and it still took several minutes to run. It did however give me the idea to take another approach and I was able to fix it.

Comment: @NilsTiebos; Vote it if it was helpfull.